# Disable resource reservation for the complete kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, rancher

Is it somehow possible to force the scheduler to ignore the available resources on a node/cluster while scheduling new pods?
We we would like to "overload" our cluster in our lab environment for testing purposes. I could not find anything about it in the docs. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are bunch of [feature flags](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-scheduler/) which you can possibly tweak to achieve it but I would say why not use `nodeName` in the pod spec and effectively bypass the scheduler.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  containers:
  - name: nginx
    image: nginx
  nodeName: kube-01
```

The above pod will run on the node `kube-01`

Answer (score 0):

This [doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling/kube-scheduler/#filtering) may help. You can try to remove the filter `PodFitsResources`.